# JQuery: parameter: hard-coded string vs ajax retrieved string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the [JQuery Token Input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) prepopulated.

```
var assignUserJson=$('#assignUserJson').val();
console.log(assignUserJson); //[{"id":"1","name":"Andrew"},{"id":"3","name":"John"}]
```

Here is a difference between two ways that I supposed it should work in:

```
$('#assignTask').tokenInput('/users/suggest', {prePopulate: assignUserJson}); // doesn't work
```

And this works:

```
$('#assignTask').tokenInput('/users/suggest', {prePopulate: [{"id":"1","name":"Andrew"},{"id":"3","name":"John"}]}); // works
```

Why is that? Shouldn't I be able to get the value from a hidden input field and pass it to the `tokenInput` function?

Comment: `assignUserJohn` is storing string representation of that json data. you need to have the actual json object not string of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first method, `assignUserJson` is a string whereas in the second method, it is an array object. Objectifying the first one should work:

```
$('#assignTask').tokenInput('/users/suggest', {prePopulate: JSON.parse(assignUserJson)});
```

Answer (score 2):

With the first method you're passing a JSON string, not a tangible JS object as you are in the second.

You would first need to parse the JSON. This can be done natively in ECMA5 or, for older browsers, via third-party support.

```
$('#assignTask').tokenInput('/users/suggest', {prePopulate: JSON.parse(assignUserJson)}); // doesn't work
```